# regex match for a string

Tags: regex, perl

I am doing a perl script which will do some formatting to an xml file.  I need some help when it comes to ignoring white space before the opening of any xml tag. I have the following xml file

test.xml

```
   <xml>
      <TI>Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates "where"  


    <VARPARA><VAR>E</VAR></VARPARA></TI>
   </xml>
```

I want a regex expression which will replace any whitespaces including extra spaces and new line characters before the opening of any xml tag with a single space, so in the above case `<VARPARA>` is the tag which has some white spaces and new line character after "where".

I was thinking something along the lines of

```
$s =~ s/\s*</ </ig;
```

but here it will look at the opening tag `<` only, whereas I want to check both the opening `<` and closing tag `>` as well so

```
    <VARPARA>
```

.

The output string should look like below

```
    <xml>
      <TI>Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates "where" <VARPARA><VAR>E</VAR></VARPARA></TI>
   </xml>
```

Comment: Why it isn't removes the spaces before `<TI>`?

Comment: How come the spaces and the new lines are still present before `<TI>` in the desired output?

Comment: for that it will check if text is found before xml tag. spaces between the tags doesn't matter if no text found in my case.

Comment: So remove trailing whitespace except when the entire text is whitespaces?

Comment: Yes you can say this.

Comment: This smacks of [parsing XML the Chtulhu way](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: @Avinash Raj, breaks comments and CDATA, at least.

Comment: @AvinashRaj regex101.com/r/vY0rD6/5 is ignoring the xml opening and closing tag, so it will still remove white space if <VARPARA> tag is not present...

Comment: it's better to go with parsers or something but not regex....

Comment: @ikegami unfortunately I can't use a parser, can i try some thing like this \s*(?:\n\n+)\s*<[A-Z|a-z]+>? the problem here is that xml tag itself is replaced. Can we use grouping in a way that it will only replace the white space and keep the tag as it?

Comment: @AvinashRaj unfortunately I can't use a parser, can i try some thing like this \s*(?:\n\n+)\s*<[A-Z|a-z]+>? the problem here is that xml tag itself is replaced. Can we use grouping in a way that it will only replace the white space and keep the tag as it?

Comment: @atif, You have to use a parser. Parsing is to assign meaning to tokens. You can try all you want, but that doesn't check if `<` is the start of a tag.

Comment: e.g., fails for `<a>   <![CDATA[  <b>  ]]></a>` in two ways.

Comment: @ikegami Guys, let's take a step back and if I say it's not an xml file and it's just a string 
"Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates where  


    |E|. this is a string". I want to remove white space before any occurrence of |E|. How do we do that? Where "E" can be any number of alphabets surrounded by ||

Comment: That's a completely different question. The original question asked "before a start tag", not "before a string". It's far more complicated because you can't search for a string to find a start tag. If you have a new question to ask, post it as a proper question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handle it.

$s =~ s/\s+(?= \<\w+>)/ /xig;

Answer (score 2):

To determine if `<` is the start of a tag, you'd have to find out if it's in comment, in a CDATA section, etc. You need more than a regex. I recommend using an existing parser.

```
use XML::LibXML qw( );

my $parser = XML::LibXML->new();
my $doc = $parser->parse_file($qfn);

for my $text_node ($doc->findnodes('//text()')) {
   my $text = $text_node->data();
   next if $text =~ /^\s+\z/;

   my $next_node = $text_node->nextSibling();
   next if !$next_node;

   $text =~ s/\s+\z/ /;
   $text_node->setData($text);
}

$doc->toFile($qfn);
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an regex expert, so this probably will fail in some scenarios, but according to your last comment try the next:

```
echo '<xml>
      <TI>Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates "where"  


    <VARPARA><VAR>E</VAR></VARPARA></TI>

<TI>Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates "where"  


    <VARPARA><VAR>E</VAR></VARPARA></TI>
</xml>' | perl -0777 -pE 's/(\S)(\s+)(<\w+?>)/$1 $3/g;s/> +</>\n</g'
<xml>
<TI>Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates "where" <VARPARA><VAR>E</VAR></VARPARA></TI>
<TI>Definitions, Exemptions and Rebates "where" <VARPARA><VAR>E</VAR></VARPARA></TI>
</xml>
```